# What is the meaning of the gradient of a current vs time graph?

Tags: electric-current

What is the meaning of the gradient of a current vs time graph?

In other words, what does the unit $As^{-1}$ or $Cs^{-2}$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

Just the "rate of change of current" very important if you are designing an electrical system but it doesn't have any particular physical meaning or it's own specific term.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of such a graph represents change in current/change in time, which is how the current changes over time.  Current is measured in Amps, (A) and time is measured in seconds (s), and therefore the units $As^{-1}$ means $\frac{A}{s}$ which is Amps per second, and represents how many amps the current changes by each second.